# SVN externals not properly displayed in TortoiseSVN's Repository Browser and locally marked as non-versioned

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals, svn-repository

I work on a (work) project that's scattered across a myriad of (source) projects and SVN locations. To make life easier, I followed a colleague's advice and set up a new folder on SVN, `/_all/`, and specified all of the other projects' trunk folders as externals:
[image: TortoiseSVN: externals definitions]

When I check `/_all` out, it dutifully pulls out all external projects. It works great.

But in my SVN Repo Browser, I can only see one of all those externals being linked in. It also seems to have the wrong overlay icon (blue instead of red arrow: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html ) Incidentally, it's the one project where there is no `trunk/` subfolder...
[image: TortoiseSVN: repo browser only showing one linked-in external project - with blue instead of red overlay arrow icon]

On top of that, TortoiseSVN seems to be unsure what to make of it all; only the one external project displayed in the Repository Browser above is recognized as "up to date" (green tick), all others get a big question mark assigned…
[image: TortoiseSVN: local overlay icons show external projects as unversioned]

Any ideas where I'm going wrong and what I need to do to...

- make all external projects show up as sub-folders (i.e. linked-in projects) on SVN?
- make TortoiseSVN locally recognize these projects as up to date?

I'd appreciate any tips to help sort this out. :)

Comment: Following advice from a colleague, I just specified a folder (instead of a path) as "local path" when setting up externals, and that worked as expected. I therefore emailed the TortoiseSVN users list to see if I might have found a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it is actually a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=634) and that there is a [workaround](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3076869), as Stefan Küng points out:

> > But regardless of that, are you saying that if I create the following
> >     folders and commit them to the ^/_all/ folder, and then add the
> >     respective externals to them (instead of to the _all/ folder
> >     directly), it would work?
> >
> > Create this folder in SVN... | ...and attach this one as an external
> >
> > ```
> > ^/_all/project1/trunk | ^/project1/trunk
> > ```
> >
> > ```
> > ^/_all/groupA/subgroup1/project2/trunk | ^/groupA/subgroup1/project2/trunk
> > ```
> >
> > ```
> > ^/_all/project3 | ^/project3
> > ```
>
> Not quite:
>
> ```
> ^/_all/project1 | ^/project1/trunk
> ```
>
> ```
> ^/_all/groupA/subgroup1/project2 | ^/groupA/subgroup1/project2/trunk
> ```
>
> ```
> ^/_all/ | ^/project3
> ```