# What's the difference between these 2 icons in TortoiseSVN Repo Browser?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

What's the difference between the following 2 icon overlays?

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.8.7.

[image]

### ADD

Thanks to the replies, I found this link: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlayed folder should represent an external link, although usually the arrow icon is red instead of blue.

An **external link** is like a pointer to a source stored in another location in the repository or even stored in a different repository.

Here it is a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131927/svn-externals-not-properly-displayed-in-tortoisesvns-repository-browser-and-loc) related to an issue on external links, where the user also wonders about the icon.

Answer (score 4):

The one with the arrow should be pointing to an [external definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html), i.e. `svn:externals`.